# How do i save exact values as displayed in JMeter test results including min, Max, avg values...?

Tags: sql-server, jmeter

I am trying to save test results as displayed in Summary, Aggregate report table but the results are not saved as the results displayed in the GUI while running jmx script.

I already tried to use Synthesis report too to get the results but still it does not work.

No error messages are displayed though.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are running in non-gui mode. Please check the below CLI sample:-

```
jmeter -n -t D:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl
```

This will generate the jtl file at the end of the execution. You can then import this file in different listeners (Summary, Aggregate etc).

If in GUI mode. Then, use simple data writer or view result tree to generate the jtl file. Once completed, use summary report "Filename" field to point generated file as input as shown below:-
[image]
Then, use "Save Table Data" button to generate a summary.csv file.

Hope this helps.